# Is "habitated" a word?

Tags: past-participles, is-it-a-word

I couldn't find it in multiple dictionaries, but have seen it used by several people. However, I do not know if this is just due to the word "sounding right", or from the word actually existing. Does anyone know if this a real word, and how one would go about finding out if it would be a real word?

Comment: The first step in finding out if it is a real word is defining "real word". That is not a term I am familiar with. What words do you consider imaginary?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this SE, so I guess I mean a "real word" is one that people actually use (as in other people have heard of it, maybe used it, and it's not just some random coincidence that I've heard many people use it). I guess another definition would be that if I wrote it on an examination, such as the SAT essay or something similar, it would not be counted as a non-existent word or incorrect if used correctly.

Comment: Well, what you probably mean is if it's a dictionary word, and it's easiest to find out by checking the dictionary.

Comment: @RegDwighт Well, *guiyguinhjig* is not a real word. Oh, wait, now it is. Darn it.

Comment: It's a real word all right. Just don't use it before checking out where it is to be used appropriately. Some examples: "Mysterious Sprites Could Be Used To Find Habitated Planets", "What percent of the earth is habitated?","was poor at college he spent most of his time habitating in his dorm room, with his food provided by his unlimited food plan, which made him habitate." (slang)

Comment: You may be looking for *[inhabited](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inhabited#Adjective)* (as an adjective). E.g. *"Earth is an inhabited planet."* (may only make sense in a science fiction context).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain *habitate* has been used by others before you.  When they used it, it usually means to dwell, and so is intransitive.

It also has a rare and, in my opinion and that of the OED, a now-obsolete transitive sense, where it is equivalent to habituate.

Per that Dictionary:

> **habitate** /ˈhæbɪteɪt/, *v. rare.*
>
> Etymology: f. L. **habitāt**-, ppl. stem of **habitāre** to dwell; but by Burton used as a derivative of **habit** *sb*.
>
> **a.** *intr.* To dwell.
>
> † **b.** *trans.* To habituate; = **habit** v.<sup>4.</sup> *Obs.*
>
> - 1621 Burton *Anat. Mel.* ɪ. ii. ɪɪ. vi, ― They being now habitated to such meditations and solitary places, can indure no company.
> - 1866 J. B. Rose tr. *Ovid’s Fasti* ᴠ. 626 ― Mars habitates in the city of his son.
> - 1866 J. B. Rose tr. *Ovid’s Fasti* ᴠɪ. 936 ― She doth habitate On Tiber’s banks.

I should definitely avoid the second sense, which would be taken as a typo for *habituate*.  The first sense sounds a mite pretentious for *dwell*, or even the fancier *inhabit*, but you might put it into the mouth of some speaker who never uses a single word when he can sneak in a paragraph, or a one-syllable word when there is a polysyllabic monstrosity he can use to scare away the easily intimidated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would the OED be the Oxford English Dictionary?

Comment: @ReliableSource Aye, and of the 2nd edition, to be exact.

Comment: On a related note: There is an entry in the OED for cohabitate, which is synonymous with cohabit (live together). It is marked as rare and obsolete.

Comment: @MattЭллен The ODAUS says *cohabitate* is a 'misbegotten back-formation' -- Nevertheless Google returns **282k** results.  (http://books.google.co.in/books?id=z_VmtjAU01YC&pg=PA67&dq=cohabitate&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Inq3UN-HNYfLrQeF-YDQBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=cohabitate&f=false)

Comment: @Kris What exactly is the ODAUS? Also, the word I'm looking for isn't really cohabitate, because I was looking for a word to describe one particular noun, not coexisting with another.

Comment: @ReliableSource I've given the link to ODAUS. The comment's about Matt's comment on *cohabitate*, not directly about the question. Regarding *habitate* itself, see my comment at the question above.

Answer (score 1):

Of course **habitated** is a word... although my browser's built-in spell-checker disagrees. Dictionaries are descriptive, not prescriptive. If you want it to be a word, then use it. I, for one, being a non-native English speaker have a clear meaning of what it is trying to convey. It won't survive a good Strunk & White'ing though.

Comment: Can't agree with "If you want it to be a word then use it". If I want "omgwtfable" to be a word, that doesn't mean I should use it here and there.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Well, you can use it, but [YANETUT](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/YANETUT).

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I disagree. I can see no reason why you shouldn't. How did all other words come to be ? omgwtfable is perfectly cromulent word.

Comment: @tchrist, well, I believe that if I use a word I would also want other people to understand it, unless, of course, I'm using it to speak to myself.

Comment: "If you want it to be a word, then use it" ... but make sure it means what you think it means.

Comment: "If you want it to be a word, then use it" ...depending on where you happen to be using it, that can be a good way to portray yourself as poorly educated. I like coloring outside the lines, too, but there's a time and place to do that, as well as times and places to _avoid_ doing that.

Comment: I endorse the spirit of this position. English is a living language with no true definitive authority. Coining new words is highly valuable. Coining new terms precludes silly arguments and preserves etymology rather than corrupting existing terms with engineered concepts. It has become trendy to supplant and conflate existing words with political or social meaning. Even when goals are noble, the effect on language is disastrous. If folks dub new terms rather than completely overriding old ones with meanings disjoint from etymology, who could even argue with them? Swell.

Comment: That said, once a term is used it only gets its own place at the table when it rises to acceptance and begins its own etymology. If the term is not especially apt, people are not likely to use it. You face an uphill battle, with good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I do know so! Because I use it all the time like in this sentence: "I habitated the house".